# When does actually start SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot application on Eclipse to try.
It has created many things, including a class **@SpringBootApplication** which has a **main** method. I imagine that this class is run first in my application. But when? When does it start exactly? I have run the project on the server (tomcat), loaded soma pages and I don't see any print of this class:

```
package com.myapp.futbol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WHEN CAN I SEE THIS????");
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);        
    }
}
```

When does start the application exactly?

Comment: If you build your application as a WAR file and deploy it into Tomcat, the main method is never run. It is only used when you package your app as JAR and run it standalone. For deployment into a servlet container, have a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: Spring boot comes with embedded tomcat server and the tomcat server will initialize your jar file by loading the main class, using embedded webserver class loader implemented by spring. This is the first class to be invoked, and @SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer class, if you run your application in --debug mode, you can see more logging w.r.t to invocation and should be able to see your print statement as first statment in your logs. Check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_startup_failure

Comment: Thanks. I was starting like this in Eclipse: Run As->Run on Server.
In this case it was starting my tomcat server. So I think that not the embedded one. When I started with Run As->Spring Boot App, I saw the prints. So, @dunni you say that to be able to deploy it to remote tomcat server I have to package it as war, right? Cannot be used as jar?